# PowerShell - Finding and modifying multiple text in string

Tags: regex, powershell

I've got the following text for example (stored as `$test`):

> \u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cimg
>   src=\"**/sites/mysite/SiteCollectionImages/banner.jpg**\" alt=\"\"
>   style=\"float:none;height: auto;width:
>   auto\"/\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eMore Meat, Less Waste, Means More Value
>   For Your
>   Dollar.\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eWhen
>   substituting Emu meat in your recipes or planning your serving
>   portions, keep in mind that low fat Emu meat will not shrink like
>   other meats. You get more of what you pay for with no bones, exterior
>   fat, or gristle. Emu meat is very shelf stable especially if vacuum
>   packaged. Properly vacuum packaged meat will keep fresh in your
>   refrigerator for up to 4 weeks, and up to 6-9 months in your
>   freezer.\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cimg
>   src=\"**/sites/mysite/SiteCollectionImages/logo.jpg**\" alt=\"\"
>   style=\"float:none;height: auto;width:
>   auto\"/\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e

I would like to update the bolded text in between `img src=\"` and `\"` (to something like `/sites/newSite/newLibrary/originalFilename.v2.jpg`)

How would I go about doing these replacements in Powershell using regex?

I've tried `$test -replace '(?<=img src=\")(?<imgUrl>\")', ' '` to start and even that doesn't do any replacements for me.

---

**Update**

I was able to capture what I needed to replace by using `$test -replace '(?<=img src=\\")(.+?)(?=\\")', '$1'` (Thanks to @user1390638)

I wanted to apply a function to `$1` before replacement so I had to do this to make it work:

`[regex]::Replace($test, '(?<=img src=\\")(.+?)(?=\\")', {param($match) someFunction($match.Groups[1].Value) })`

Comment: Updated my answer to apply a "scramble" function to the matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, to match the string between you should use the following regex.

- First part of the regex (?<=img src=\") will find the img src=\" text inside your text variable. Note that you should escape \ character here.
- Second part of the regex .+? gets everything between, ? means non-greedy, so it will stop at the first match
- Last part of the regex (?=") means until quote.

`(?<=img src=\\").+?(?=")`

Assuming your text is assigned to $text variable.

```
$text -replace('(?<=img src=\\").+?(?=")',"/sites/newSite/newLibrary/originalFilename.v2.jpg")
```

To replace multiple texts, you can basically call -replace twice such as $text -replace(...) -replace(...)

Comment: I see, but I still want to capture the match hence me using `<imgUrl>` so I can do some modifications on the replacement based on the original. How would I go about this?

Basically the replacement text would be a parameter to some function that will give out the new image URL... so I was thinking of something like `$test -replace [pattern<imgUrl>], someFunction(imgUrl)`. Is this even possible?

Comment: If what you want to do is to call the function on the input, you can assign the result into a variable like this `$scrambled_url = scramble('$1')`  before calling replace, and then use this $scrambled_url variable in your replace function `-replace('your pattern', $scrambled_url )` if this is what you want to do.

Comment: If you want to call function on the matched url, first you can get the matched url with -match `$text -match '(?<=img src=\\").+?(?=")'` once you call match, -match operator sets a special variable called $matches. You can get the matched string from this variable and call your function `$scrambled_url = someFunction(-matches[0])` . After that you can call the replace function with this $scrambled_url like in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Regex

```sh
(?<=img src=\\\").+?(?=\\)

(?<=img src=\\\") # Finds `img src=\` escaping `\` and `"`  
.+?               # Everything between the two outer capture groups  
(?=\\)            # To the next backslash, again escaping the `\`
```

If you want to capture the url first to do other stuff with it, you can create a new regex object to check your matches.

```bsh
$obj = # Import your text here how you like
$regex = [regex]::new('(?<=img src=\\\").+?(?=\\)')
$matches = $regex.Matches($obj)
```

You could create new variables for what you want to change the path to and then use the matches to replace the text. Adding a scramble function.

```bsh
function Scramble {
    Param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string]$InputObject
    )

    $split = $InputObject -split "/" | Select-Object -Skip 1
    return "/" + (($split | Get-Random -Count $split.Count) -join "/")
}

foreach ($match in $matches) {
    $obj.Replace($match.Value, ($match.Value | Scramble))  # .Net Method here to replace the specific string found. No need for another regex.
}
```